# Where do controller methods for rails_admin custom actions go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I created a custom action in RailsAdmin using https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-action, but I'm unsure where I would put my controller methods within the custom action and if I use a form what would be the path to call those controller methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of a custom action I'm using for pdf (project [here](https://github.com/stephskardal/rails_admin_pdf)):

```
require "rails_admin_pdf/engine"

module RailsAdminPdf
end

require 'rails_admin/config/actions'

module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class Pdf < Base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)

        register_instance_option :member do
          true
        end

        register_instance_option :controller do
          Proc.new do
            report = "#{@object.class.to_s.demodulize}Report".constantize.new
            send_data report.to_pdf(@object), :filename => "#{@object.class.to_s.demodulize}_#{@object.id}.pdf", :type => "application/pdf"  
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So, to answer your question, the controller method goes inside the lib/rails_admin_*custom_action_name*.rb module. I'm not sure I understand the second part of your question regarding form submission. You can check out another example of a custom action with form submission [here](https://github.com/stephskardal/rails_admin_import).

Comment: I created a global action at the root level which is a site search using sunspot and was hoping to avoid some spaghetti code. I didn't know how to apply your example to a root level custom action, but it was very handy for model custom actions. I also posted a thread on Google Groups and Benoit also mentioned I can only have a block evaluated in a controller action. Thanks Steph!  https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rails_admin/SWzKt3y2CCI/discussion

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but a coworker of mine just wrote about creating a custom Rails action as part of the main Rails app (not as a gem): http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/03/railsadmin-custom-action-case-study.html

Comment: Thanks. I've been following you guys on Endpoint and its been a big help. RailsAdmin has been great so far, but I hope future versions will make this process easier.

Comment: Thanks to the article maker, it has explained the process in an easy way.